# How I can create Linked Server on Linux SQLServer 2017

Tags: sql-server

It is possible to create linked server from SQLServer 2017 on Linux, to Oracle database,

which steps are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Linked server to Oracle is not supported

> **Unsupported features & services**
>
> - Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server

see [unsupported features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-linux-2017#Unsupported).

if you want to create linked server to a SQL server, then below T-sql will work (I have tested it and it works fine)

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
     @server = N'serverB', -- destination server Name 
     @srvproduct = N'',
     @provider = N'SQLNCLI',
     @datasrc = N'xx.xx.xx.xx', -- IP address of the destination server 
     @catalog = N'master'; -- db Name 
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
     @rmtsrvname = N'serverB',-- destination server Name 
     @useself = N'False',
     @locallogin = NULL,
     @rmtuser = N'sa', -- remote login name 
     @rmtpassword = '#######'; -- remote login password 
GO
```

Comment: Ok, I will Try It! ...